# Run code after the caller of the event handler has exited

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

In the following example, Is it possible to execute `Do X` after the control's `Do Y` is done (i.e., exited the method in which my event handler is called)? It seems the action of `Do X` messes up with `Do Y`, so `Do X` needs to be done after `Do Y` is done.

```
//at form initialisation
someThirdPartyControl.MouseDoubleClick += MyHandler;

void MyHandler(...)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    //Do X
}

//The control's code may be something like
class SomeThirdPartyControl:Control
{
  void override OnMouseDoubleClick(...)
  {
     //call event handlers
     //Do Y
  }
}
```

`Do X` potentially changes the size of the control, so that the location of the items may change, and when that happens the control wrongly selects the item where the mouse pointer is after the double click. For example, I double-clicked `Item 4`, but `Do X` changes the control's size, and after `Do X` is done, `Item 2` is beneath the mouse pointer, and the control selects `Item 2`. What I want is that the selected item remains `Item 4`.

Comment: It seems a case of an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Can you explain what are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have added the problem of the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this if you subclass `SomeControl` and override `OnMouseDoubleClick` like this:

```
class MyControl:SomeControl
{
  void override OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e)
     //call event handlers
     //Do X
  }
}
```

You could even go as far as defining a new event `AfterMouseDoubleClick` and fire that event instead of calling X in `OnMouseDoubleClick`.

```
class MyControl:SomeControl
{
  public event MouseButtonEventHandler AfterMouseDoubleClick;

  void override OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e)
     //call event handlers
     OnAfterMouseDoubleClick(e)
  }

  void virtual OnAfterMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     if(AfterMouseDoubleClick != null)
       AfterMouseDoubleClick(this, e)
  }
}
```

However you should really consider what you are doing in X to mess up Y.

Comment: Basically, `Do X` potentially changes the size of the control, so that the location of the items may change, and when that happens the control wrongly selects the item where the mouse pointer is after the double click (the selected item should not change).

Comment: And here I edited my answer to make it more different than yours and you had to go and update it :p

Comment: @DamnVegetables what you could do is queue the work that will cause the size to change in a `this.BeginInvoke` call. That will execute the code that changes the size after all other things have been processed in the event queue.

Comment: Sorry about that. I had already mentioned about the posibility of AfterMouseDown, then thought I should also provide some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very easy, you just need to inherit from `SomeThirdPartyControl`. You could even turn it in to another event and use it that way.

```
class MyWrapperControl : SomeThirdPartyControl
{
  public event MouseEventHandler AfterMouseDoubleClick;

  protected void override OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e); //This will Do X.

     OnAfterMouseDoubleClick(e);
  }

  protected virtal void OnAfterMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
       var temp = AfterMouseDoubleClick;
       if(temp != null)
           temp(this, e);
  }
}
```

used like.

```
//at form initialisation
myWrapperControl.AfterMouseDoubleClick += MyHandler;

void MyHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //This event is fired after all MouseDoubleClick events have been handled.

    //Do X
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The base implementation of OnMouseDoubleClick calls the event, so:

1. MyHandler won't be fired if you don't call the base implementation from OnMouseDoubleClick()
2. You can control the order of invocation by putting base.OnMouseDoubleClick() wherever you need it to be.

   ```
   void override OnMouseDoubleClick(...)
   {
       // ...
       // Do Y
       base.OnMouseDoubleClick(); // Does X among other things...
   }
   ```